# Client in BLE for raspberry Pi 4 using BlueZ

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, raspberry-pi4, bluez

The example server and client provided at the BlueZ github do not work (I tested them both on two raspberry PIs, one with client and one with server). I tried first the server with the nRF Connect app on my phone and could not detect any services advertised by it. So, I used another server/peripheral code provided by:

https://punchthrough.com/creating-a-ble-peripheral-with-bluez/

This server works perfectly and I can find all my created services and characterisitics in the nRF connect application. However, now I have no idea how to get the client to work.

I tried the client files from here:

https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/test/example-gatt-client

I added my own service and characteristic UUIDs that I confirmed to be correctly advertised using the nRF Connect app. However, this code does not work at all. The main from the code I used is given as below, the rest of the functions are the same as the example code from BlueZ but with my own service and characteritics with their UUID.

```
def main():
    # Set up the main loop.
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    global bus
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    global mainloop
    mainloop = GObject.MainLoop()

    om = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, '/'), DBUS_OM_IFACE)
    om.connect_to_signal('InterfacesRemoved', interfaces_removed_cb)
    print(om)
    print('Getting objects...')
    objects = om.GetManagedObjects()
    
    adapter = 0

    for o, props in objects.items():
        if GATT_MANAGER_IFACE in props.keys():
            adapter = o
    
    if not adapter:
        logger.critical("GattManager1 interface not found")
        return
    print(adapter)
    adapter_obj = bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, adapter)

    adapter_props = dbus.Interface(adapter_obj, "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")

    # powered property on the controller to on
    adapter_props.Set("org.bluez.Adapter1", "Powered", dbus.Boolean(1))

    print(objects)
    chrcs = []

    # List characteristics found
    for path, interfaces in objects.items():
        if GATT_CHRC_IFACE not in interfaces.keys():
            continue
        chrcs.append(path)
        print(chrcs)

    # List sevices found
    for path, interfaces in objects.items():
        if GATT_SERVICE_IFACE not in interfaces.keys():
            continue

        chrc_paths = [d for d in chrcs if d.startswith(path + "/")]

        if process_thispi_service(path, chrc_paths):
            break

    if not thispi_service:
        print('This Pi Service not found')
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print('This Pi Service found')
    start_client()

    mainloop.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output I got by using print statements at different points were:

```
<Interface <ProxyObject wrapping <dbus._dbus.SystemBus (system) at 0x7fb26f0b30> :1.18 / at 0x7fb26cedd0> implementing 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager' at 0x7fb26e1fd0>
Getting objects...
/org/bluez/hci0

[dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service0082/char0083')]
[dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service0082/char0083'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char007c')]
[dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service0082/char0083'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char007c'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0079')]
[dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service0082/char0083'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char007c'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0079'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0076')]
[dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service0082/char0083'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char007c'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0079'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0076'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0074')]
[dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service0082/char0083'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char007c'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0079'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0076'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0074'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0071')]
[dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service0082/char0083'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char007c'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0079'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0076'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0074'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0071'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char006e')]
[dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service0082/char0083'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char007c'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0079'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0076'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0074'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0071'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char006e'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char006b')]
[dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service0082/char0083'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char007c'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0079'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0076'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0074'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0071'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char006e'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char006b'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0069')]
[dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service0082/char0083'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char007c'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0079'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0076'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0074'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0071'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char006e'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char006b'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0069'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0066')]
[dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service0082/char0083'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char007c'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0079'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0076'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0074'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0071'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char006e'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char006b'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0069'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0066'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0063')]
[dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service0082/char0083'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char007c'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0079'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0076'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0074'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0071'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char006e'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char006b'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0069'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0066'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0063'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A/service005a/char0060')]



















dbus.Dictionary({dbus.String('UUID'): dbus.String('00001855-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', variant_level=1), dbus.String('Device'): dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A', variant_level=1), dbus.String('Primary'): dbus.Boolean(True, variant_level=1), dbus.String('Includes'): dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('o'), variant_level=1)}, signature=dbus.Signature('sv'))
dbus.Dictionary({dbus.String('UUID'): dbus.String('0000184c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', variant_level=1), dbus.String('Device'): dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A', variant_level=1), dbus.String('Primary'): dbus.Boolean(True, variant_level=1), dbus.String('Includes'): dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('o'), variant_level=1)}, signature=dbus.Signature('sv'))
dbus.Dictionary({dbus.String('UUID'): dbus.String('00001849-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', variant_level=1), dbus.String('Device'): dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A', variant_level=1), dbus.String('Primary'): dbus.Boolean(True, variant_level=1), dbus.String('Includes'): dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('o'), variant_level=1)}, signature=dbus.Signature('sv'))
dbus.Dictionary({dbus.String('UUID'): dbus.String('00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', variant_level=1), dbus.String('Device'): dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_24_95_2F_D3_5C_6A', variant_level=1), dbus.String('Primary'): dbus.Boolean(True, variant_level=1), dbus.String('Includes'): dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('o'), variant_level=1)}, signature=dbus.Signature('sv'))
This Pi Service not found

Process ended with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Note: I am trying to connect two raspberry PI together using BLE, one will work as client and other as server. I have working server or peripheral but not client.